# Dynamics AX String Operations on E-mail format

Tags: regex, string, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a str like this;

```
"B S <b.s@msoft.com>; J T <j.t@msoft.com>; A M <a.m@msoft.com>"
```

and i want to return to this format;

```
"b.s@msoft.com, j.t@msoft.com, a.m@msoft.com"
```

how i can do this?

---

```cs
str mail, a, mnew;
int b, c;
List strlist = new List(Types::String);
ListIterator iterator;
mail = "B S <b.s@msoft.com>; J T <j.t@msoft.com>; A M <a.m@msoft.com>";

strlist = strSplit(mail,';');

iterator = new ListIterator(strlist);

while (iterator.more())
{
    if (strcontains(iterator.value(), "<"))
    {
        b = strFind(iterator.value(), "<", 1, strLen(iterator.value()));
        c = strFind(iterator.value(), ">", 1, strLen(iterator.value()));
        info(strFmt("%1",subStr(strRem(iterator.value(),'>'),b+1,c)));
    }
    else
    {
        info(strFmt("%1",strLRTrim(iterator.value())));
    }
    iterator.next();
}
```

I do this with string runtime funtions. How can do it with regexp?

Comment: I hope those are fake emails. Are you missing a `>` after `brandon[...]@[...].com`? If yes, then it looks like you can look for pairs of `<` and `>` symbols and take the text between them to build your result. Do you want to implement this in [tag:x++]? Are you familiar with regular expressions? What version of Dynamics AX are you using?

Comment: Hi FH-Inway, thanks for your answer. Yes these are fake emails and yes i missed > after first e-mail, sorry. I am using Dynamics AX 2012 R3, and i will use it in a job in MorphX. How can i do this  "look for pairs of < and > symbols and take the text between them to build your result." ? I tried string runtime functions but i didn't, please help me

Comment: Could you [edit] into your question what issues you had with the string runtime functions? If you add some code of the job you have tried so far, you will have better chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Can you help me for solution with regexp ? @FH-Inway

Comment: Well, [you know what they say about regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) ;) But take a look at https://regex101.com/r/QAqBXC/2 and http://fourone.se/blog/2009/10/02/using-regular-expressions-in-dynamics-ax/ to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check below one of the possible examples with regular expressions:

```cs
TextBuffer  textBuffer = new TextBuffer();
int         pos, len;
str         res;
;

textBuffer.setText("Brandon Smith <brandon.smith@msoft.com>; Jake Tyler <jake.tyler@msoft.com>; Amelia Miler <amelia.miler@msoft.com>");
textBuffer.regularExpressions(true);

while (textBuffer.find(@'\<[a-z0-9.@]+\>', pos))
{
    pos = textBuffer.matchPos();
    len = textBuffer.matchLen();

    res = (res == '') ? textBuffer.subStr(pos, len) : res + ', ' + textBuffer.subStr(pos, len);

    pos++;
}

textBuffer.setText(res);
textBuffer.removeChar('<>');

info(textBuffer.getText());
```

[image: infolog]

Comment: @Busra Consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: Thanks for your warning @FH-Inway